# How to disable entire content of Mat-Expansion Panel?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application in which I have created many Mat-Expansion Panels dynamically depending on user input. When a checkbox(also created dynamically) next to the Mat expansion panel is selected, I have disabled the corresponding panel which works correctly. However the issue is that when the panel is open and I click the checkbox, only the header of the panel gets disabled, but the content inside it is still functional. I would like to do one of the following:

- Disable the entire content of the panel.

  OR
- Close the panel when checkbox is clicked.

Since this is a reactive forms approach, I am unable to use [disabled] on the contents inside of the panel.

Is there a way to close the panel from the typescript file? (perhaps using @ViewChild(), but since many panels are created dynamically, how do I get a unique name? I have unique names but how do I pass it to TS)

Any other approach is welcome.

Comment: Is your dynamically created checkbox created at the same time your panel is ? If so, you might be able to pass a reference of your panel to your checkbox click handler, and access it in your click handler function (and therefore be able to control at least its collapse property). If this does not reflect perfectly your case, please provide some code to elaborate a proper solution.

Comment: Yes it is created at the same time. I tried to pass a reference and use the collapse property but it didn't work. Maybe I am doing it the wrong way. If possible, could you please illustrate with an example? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Easiest way - and fastest - would be you to provide your current code in a stackblitz and I try to make it work.